# How to send a ping pc to another pc which are placed in different networks

Tags: cisco

[LOCAL AREA NETWORKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SERPV.png)

I want to send a ping using command prompt from one PC to another PC which are placed in different networks. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: With a VPN tunnel. You cant talk directly to a pc on a different network with each others local addresses.

Comment: Shouldn't that router take care of it already?

Answer (score 0):

So no one did edit the question or did answer you...

So you can simple ping the other PC with the `ping IP` command (via the PC's terminal). The router will route the request if it is configured correctly.

 
 You can just save the packet tracer and share it here so we can help you better, since this information alone is not enough.